# Implicit member functions of a Class in C++

Tags: c++

The implicit member functions of a Class in C++ are:
As per wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions

**Default constructor** (if no other constructor is explicitly declared)

**Copy constructor** if no move constructor or move assignment operator is explicitly declared.If a destructor is declared generation of a copy constructor is deprecated.

**Move constructor** if no copy constructor, move assignment operator or destructor is explicitly declared.

**Copy assignment operator** if no move constructor or move assignment operator is explicitly declared.If a destructor is declared generation of a copy assignment operator is deprecated.

**Move assignment operator** if no copy constructor, copy assignment operator or destructor is explicitly declared.

**Destructor**

As per link below:

http://archives.cs.iastate.edu/documents/disk0/00/00/02/43/00000243-02/lcpp_136.html

A default constructor (i.e., one with no parameters, (section 12.1 [Ellis-Stroustrup90]), if no constructor (with any number of arguments) for the class has been declared.

A copy constructor (section 12.1 [Ellis-Stroustrup90]), if no copy constructor has been declared.

A destructor (section 12.4 [Ellis-Stroustrup90]), if no destructor has been declared.

**An assignment operator** (sections 5.17 and 12.8 of [Ellis-Stroustrup90]), if no assignment operator has been declared.

As per link below:

http://www.picksourcecode.com/ps/ct/16515.php

default constructor

copy constructor

assignment operator

default destructor

**address operator**

Can some one give code examples for : **Move constructor,Copy assignment operator,Move assignment operator,An assignment operator,address operator**
where they are being used as implicit member functions and not defined explicitly.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

/* Empty struct. No function explicitly defined. */    
struct Elem
{ };

/* Factory method that returns an rvalue of type Elem. */
Elem make_elem()
{ return Elem(); }


int main() {

  /* Use implicit move constructor (the move may be elided
     by the compiler, but the compiler won't compile this if
     you explicitly delete the move constructor): */
  Elem e1 = make_elem();

  /* Use copy assignment: */
  Elem e2;
  e2 = e1;

  /* Use move assignment: */    
  e2 = make_elem();

  /* Use address operator: */    
  std::cout << "e2 is located at " << &e2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The example above uses an empty class. You can fill it with data members that have real move semantics (i.e. members where moving is really different from copying), e.g. a `std::vector`, and you'll get move semantics automatically without defining move constructors or move assignment operators specifically for your class.

Comment: /* Use copy assignment: */
  Elem e2;
  e2 = e1;  
This explaind copy constructor and assignment operator as well , right?

Comment: `e2 = e1` is a copy assignment, it does not involve the copy constructor (because `e2` is not constructed -- it exists already). If you want the copy constructor, you'd need to say `Elem e2 = e1;` all on one line.

Comment: How would you differentiate assignment operator and copy assignment then?

Comment: `e2 = e1;` is copy assignment, `e2 = make_elem();` is move assignment. Both are assignment operators, and both are implicitly defined. (But "assignment operator" is a term with an even broader meaning, e.g. `e2 = 3;` or `e2 += 12.3;` use assignment operators, too, but those are not defined implicitly, you'd have to define them yourself (as `operator=(int)` and `operator+=(float)`, respectively).